# getBoolean(String str) and valueOf(String str) of Boolean class gives different output

Tags: java, boolean

I am surprised to know that `getBoolean()` and `valueOf()` method returns different results for the same input string.

I have tried to pass the `"true"` to both the methods. But `getBoolean()` gives me false output whereas `valueOf()` gives me right output that is true. Why?

Comment: Relevant: http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2009/12/java-booleans-getboolean-useful-if-not.html

Comment: What language is this? If it's Java, note that the argument to `getBoolean` isn't a string representing a Boolean value; it's a string naming a system property whose value is supposed to be a string representing a Boolean value.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[**The API-documentation is your friend.**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html)

- [`Boolean.getBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) probably doesn't do what you think it does:

  > *Returns true if and only if the [**system property**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) named by the argument exists and is equal to the string "true".*

- [`Boolean.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28boolean%29) is probably what you're looking for:

  > *The Boolean returned represents the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".*

Comment: `Boolean.getBoolean` must be the stupidest method the worst placed method

Answer (score 5):

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) of getBoolean clearly state that it searches the System Properties. The value that you pass to it is the name of the system property, not a "true" or "false" string.

E.g., `var b = Boolean.getBoolean("some.property");

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean.getBoolean` must be the worst placed method in java. One of the big WTF.

Why wasn't it placed in `System` or `Properties` or whatever?

So to answer your question - yes, it is a very confusing thing and you can just click on the method in your IDE to see the code or read the javadoc.

Here's the source code:

```
 public static boolean getBoolean(String name) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            result = toBoolean(System.getProperty(name));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I too found this issue recently when using Boolean.getBoolean() . In addition if you want to have a null check you can use Boolean.parseBoolean which will return false in case of nulls

Comment: While loading System property using Boolean.getBoolean("property.name"), there is no need to worry about Nulls. The API clearly talks about it. This API returns true if and only if the system property named by the argument exists and is equal to the string "true" (case insensitive). It otherwise returns "false".

Answer (score 0):

```
class Boo1
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
       System.setProperty("true","true");
       System.setProperty("false","true");

       boolean d=Boolean.getBoolean("true");

       System.out.println(d);   
   }
}
```